# How to host a website on kali linux virtualbox machine?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, kali-linux, web, hosts

I have a puzzle, shown here: [http://imgur.com/a/ijyPf](https://imgur.com/a/ijyPf).

How do I host my website on a Kali Linux virtual machine? How do I access my website with my public IP?

Comment: Although your question is beyond unclear, from what I understand, I think what you want is to set your NIC in VBox from NAT to Bridged.

Comment: Short answer: Please, please, PLEASE don't do this. Get a real distro, use an actual webhosting service.

Comment: You install windows 10 on your hard drive and make sure virtualizatuon is enabled in your bios, Then install virtual box with its extensions, Then download kali Linux from the source and direct virtual box to the kali.iso and install it, presto. Once you have kali up, Go into /etc/hosts and add your ethernet or WiFi Ipv4 followed by a space then your Domain name you want, Then a space and your host name, then set your host name with hostnamectl, that way you link your host name with the domain name, Then you'll want to install Apache2 and resolvconf, resolvconf is going to hold

Comment: Search "your domain name"  and your Ipv4 for your domain name you set in hosts, Then in apache make sure you enable https by allowing ssl and direct the Apache application file to var/www/html and you'll have a secure website with a domain name inside of a virtual box. You get the general idea

Comment: If you want the host name to be for your windows 10 but on your kali linux, I'm not sure if that's possible even if your forward with ittables, the routers ports and by enabling forwarding, pretty sure your domain name has to be on the machine you side in, but you can ping the kali domain from windows 10, I'm starting to get confused lol

Comment: But I mean if you're going to have a domain name and a website active from apache2  then you my as well set up a dns resolver like bind9 so you don't have to use 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 nameservers, you can just use your ethernet or WiFi ipv4 as a nameserver, bind9 is a Great place to start, if you want to question which dns just use sudo apt-cache search  servers

Comment: Yeah what schaiba said, instead of using NAT in virtual box switch it to bridge that way your virtual machine uses the same ipv4 as your host machine, I never like revealing my real ipv4 for any reason though because you can figure out a lot from those 32 lil bits, if your host is up, the ports that are open, perhaps your mac, your network, your netmask, etc, etc. People are sneaky, shhhhh

Answer (score 3):

So you want to host a wordpress website, on kali linux, inside a virtualbox virtual machine, under a windows host?

How many bad decisions does a man need to do to arrive in this situation?

If you want an answer, http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/

But if you want a real answer, I highly suggest you to reconsider what you need to do and do it in a proper way.

Comment: i should use NAT or bridged?

Comment: and ip virtualbox not change, even NAT or bridged, it is 10.0.2.15, not 192.168.(...), what I gonna type in linksys page in "to IP address". ? And this tutorial is not connect to pc host, so my problem really clear.